# Datepicker in wrong position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

[image] I am developing an php aplication and I used datepicker javascript. The problem with this is that if I scroll down it does not appear in the right position. It gets really bad if the page gets too long, the date picker is not even visible.

I am using IExplorer, it might be outdated. It is not a solution to update the browser, cause this needs to run on 200+ PCs

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){ $("#udate").datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}); });
</script>
<input type="text" id="udate" name="udate">
```

Code as requested by comment

```
<style type="text/css">
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
    size:8;
}
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

Comment: Even on 200+ PC a newer version of IE can be installed. There's no installing limit.

Comment: You might want to add a CSS tag, seeing as element positioning is easily done using CSS

Comment: check in other browsers also

Comment: @wumm: I'm assuming OP is not a sys-admin, and some companies have this ridiculous, webdev torturing policy of supporting older browsers, and enforce this lunacy by having internal apps run on those browsers, too. I've worked in places like those... still having nightmares because of it

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){ $("#udate").datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}); });
</script>
<input type="text" id="udate" name="udate">

Comment: I know IE can be installed but it would be ridicolous of an intern to ask the IT desk to go arround the factory and update all computers. CSS could work but I have no iddea how to reference the position to the text input I am using.

Comment: looks like a position property problem with tables. can you try adding a `position:relative` to your cell in which the input field is?

Comment: @user3864308 THAT IS the job of the Systemadministrator...to make sure everything is up to date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this work around to adjust position of datepicker after it opens (please adjust position as per your requirement)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(function(){ 
        $("#udate").datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}); 
        // bind click event and adjust datepicker position.
        $(".hasDatepicker").click(function(e){
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").css({'top':e.pageY+20,'left':e.pageX-250});
        });
  });
</script>

<input type="text" id="udate" name="udate">
```

Comment: This makes it appear where it should be if the page was not scrolled down. It seems like it does not take into account the scrool.

Comment: did not understand what are saying, can you please share jsfiddle link.

Comment: I'm not using jsfiddle. Just notepad. It looks the same, just a little moved. If you look at the original liked image you can see that it is direcly above the input field which it is ok. If the page would have not returned so many results the position would be right.

Comment: Thats what I said, you need to adjust position as per your requirement. You need to manipulate `top` and `left` values.

Answer (score 2):

If the datepicker is generated inside the container this wouldn't be a problem.
See this

```
Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jbK6a/15/
```

I placed the datepicker behind the input with the beforeShow event.

And I used position: relative; on the scrollable container so that the absolute element listens to the container.

Or Allow the scroll for your list and fix the Date picker.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the CSS. If I disable the it it works perfect.

Comment: I had this problem, but only on mobile devices. Simply adding a container/wrapper div with position: relative; fixed the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you got

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of your html output.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer. Besides: that won't solve the issue... I suspect this isn't even the cause of it

Comment: I have this later in the code, after some includes. If I move it up it disables all my CSS dunno why, some tags migth not be closed.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem well, it was the answer to a lot of my jQuery display problems in IE.

Comment: @user3864308: ??? later in the code??? the doctype _has_ to be at the very top of your markup!

Comment: its after include styles.css and connect.css. If i put it at the top it disables the css. If I move it to an other system the styles dont work at all. I'm lost.

Comment: @user3864308: then please post the top of your file too. i don't know where you insert the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but it should be at the very start of your html output, not at the start of your php script.

Comment: @northkildonan:     added the top part of the code as received from the source

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a combination of the answers.
For start I did what norhkildonan said:

> make sure you got
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> ```
>
> at the top of your html output.

Then edited a bit the css and after that added Bhushan Kawadkar part:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
>   $(function(){ 
>         $("#udate").datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}); 
>         // bind click event and adjust datepicker position.
>         $(".hasDatepicker").click(function(e){
>             $("#ui-datepicker-div").css({'top':e.pageY+20,'left':e.pageX-250});
>         });
>   });
> </script>
>
> <input type="text" id="udate" name="udate">
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding the class 'container' where I needed it attached.